# Change iBeacon UUID (or Major/Minor) with Custom iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

Has anyone had success with configuring non-name brand iBeacons (eg. https://www.ebay.com/itm/NRF51822-2V-3-3V-bluetooth-4-0-wireless-module-for-ibeacon-base-stat-JF/254232206096?hash=item3b316b9b10:g:TT4AAOSwaMtcnXbr) with an iOS app?

I have an app running that can scan for these beacons just fine, but my target application involves modification of the beacon UUID which (as far as I understand) is fairly contingent on the SDK provided by the maker of the beacon. Things like Estimote are pretty clear about their SDK capabilities but the beacons are a bit too expensive and bulky.

Open to literally any input or recommendations, I'm hitting a wall here.

Thanks.

Comment: I had a successful project with this one https://accent-systems.com/product/ibks-105/

Comment: It really depends if that beacon is configurable or not. There is a "not modifiable mode", it just advertise. And there is an editable one in BLE (other characteristics writable, etc.). Of course, if you have access (pin/usb, etc.) you might modify it, but it really depends on the software inside the device.

Answer (score 0):

The provider of the beacons should have a configuration app available. Avoid providers without such an app.

Even though iBeacon is exactly specified, configuring such beacons is not, so apps are not interchangeable.

I've used Wellcore beacons successfully, that are quite competitive on price when ordered directly from China. I made a free configuration app for them, based on their SDK, as there was no such app in English: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abiro.cliqtagsbeaconwriter
I got bad reviews as Wellcore changed chipset without telling me, so the app stopped working, but that's fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Have you heard of Moko beacons (https://www.mokosmart.com/mokosmart-r9-beacon-ultra-thin-electronic-tags-supporting-ibeacon/)? I came across them while researching Wellcore beacons. They seem to be more in line with the size I'm looking for.

Comment: No, but they look like the beacons Minew sell. Who actually produces in China can be hard to figure out. Supposedly Satech makes Minew's beacons.